# How to expand a Quick launch by default?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have added metadata navigation as explained from the below site, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-A8DDFCD1-A486-4E0F-B1B1-F10CA79FA9BC

Can i use some CSS or javascript to expand this by default?

Answer (score 0):

You may check TreeView_PopulateNode for this.

Here is the thread.

http://letsdosharepoint.com/auto-expand-metadata-navigation-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the Managed Metadata selection by doing this steps:

**1. Get the ID of your "expansion link"**

Open the SharePoint page in Internet Explorer. Press F12 for opening the developer tools. Switch in ribbon to "Elements" if not active. Activate the two little icons left of the word "Elements" for highlighting and selecting elements in your page.

Next hover the little triangle which allows you to expand the Managed Metadata navigation. You will see the source code jump to the element you selected now.

Look for the hyperlink beginning with

Copy the id and save somewhere.

**2. Create the script for expanding**

Then create a text file (extension .txt) and open it in editor. Insert the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function Expand()
{ try { TreeView_PopulateNode(ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl04_WebTreeView_Data,1,document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl04_WebTreeViewn1'),document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl04_WebTreeViewt1'),document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl04_WebTreeViewt1i'),' ','Project Type','Metadata Navigation\\Project Type','t','30:FieldNameNode:bec55f5d-019b-43af-bcd4-990e2a6bfb8c:4b9b8b11-ed3b-41c4-ae38-a2ae217de5e1:2e23af5c-f1e7-4692-966c-bee1a079eedd:30|ListNode|bec55f5d-019b-43af-bcd4-990e2a6bfb8c|4b9b8b11-ed3b-41c4-ae38-a2ae217de5e1|95af593a-620c-4751-b5b4-470c7bd0445f','tt');
}
catch (err) { }
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Expand");
</script>
```

Within the code replace the id `ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl04_WebTreeView_Data` with your id gathered in the first step. Replace the `Project Type` with the title of your Managed Metadata as well.

As you have saved this textfile somewhere on your computer we are ready to do the last step.

**3. Place the script on your page**

Upload the text file somewhere into your site assets. Copy the hyperlink to the file and keep it in your clipboard.

Open the page where you want to expand the Managed Metadata, edit the page and insert a Content Editor Webpart. As you open the Webpart Properties you can insert the hyperlink to your text file stored in your site assets. As you save page your script will be loaded upon page load an expand the navigation as you wanted to.